# AzureAD Powershell Updating User's Hire Dates

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am trying to run a Powershell script that imports a CSV file, then will loop through and update Users's Hire Dates in AzureAD.

```
# Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD

# Path to the CSV file containing user data
$csvPath = "C:\Users\#######\Downloads\20231218_hire_date.csv"

# Import CSV data
$userData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

# Iterate through each user in the CSV and update their hire date
foreach ($row in $userData) {
    # Get the user by UPN (User Principal Name)
    $userPrincipalName = $row.'UserPrincipalName'
    $targetUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'"

    # Check if the user is found
    if ($targetUser) {
        # Update the user's hire date attribute
        $hireDate = $row.'EmployeeHireDate'
        Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $targetUser.ObjectId -ExtensionProperty EmployeeHireDate $hireDate
        Write-Host "Updated hire date for user $($user.UserPrincipalName) to $($user.EmployeeHireDate)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "User with UPN $($user.UserPrincipalName) not found."
    }
}
```

I think everything is set up correctly, at least to my eyes but I'm getting and error that has to do with the data type.

Does the date need to be converted in the CSV file, or can the script convert what is already included?

[Photo of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI4x9.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered is likely because the date value you're passing is not accepted. Additionally, verify the `ExtensionProperty` named **EmployeeHireDate**.

[image]

If **EmployeeHireDate** exists as a property, you can update the date value for that property. If it's not available, kindly create the attribute using the command below.

```
$MyApp = (New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "Employee join Date").ObjectId
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId (Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString "Employee join Date").AppId
New-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty -ObjectId $MyApp -Name "EmployeejoinDate" -DataType "String" -TargetObjects "User"
```

If you're attempting to update the `EmployeejoinDate` value using the user's creation date property, you can use the command below.

```
$userjoindate = $targetUser.ExtensionProperty.createdDateTime
$dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
$dateObject = [DateTime]::ParseExact($userjoindate, $dateFormat, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Here is the PowerShell code to update extension attribute value.

```
$csvPath = "/home/mindtree/venkat/exportUsers_2023-12-19.csv"

# Import CSV data
$userData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

# Iterate through each user in the CSV and update their hire date
foreach ($row in $userData) {
    # Get the user by UPN (User Principal Name)
    $userPrincipalName = $row.'UserPrincipalName'
    $targetUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'"

    # Check if the user is found

    if ($targetUser) {
      
      # i update value from user creation date
        $userjoindate = $targetUser.ExtensionProperty.createdDateTime
        $dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
        $dateObject = [DateTime]::ParseExact($userjoindate, $dateFormat, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

#For updating random date value
$dateObject = Get-Date "12/19/2023"
$dateString = $dateObject.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
----------------------------------------------

        # Update the user's hire date attribute

        Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $targetUser.ObjectId -ExtensionName "extension_c4874bb532d2436b80ea2c5da29b5a47_EmployeejoinDate" -ExtensionValue $dateObject
        Write-Host "Updated hire date for user $($targetUser.UserPrincipalName)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "User with UPN $userPrincipalName not found."
    }
}
```

After executing the code, the user's extension attribute values are updated successfully.

[image]

[image]

Reference: [Create a new extension property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0#create-a-new-extension-property)